# For loop in pandas dataframe using enumerate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, enumerate

I have a basic dataframe which is a result of a gruopby from unclean data:

```
 df:

Name1   Value1  Value2
A       10      30
B       40      50
```

I have created a list as follows:

```
Segment_list = df['Name1'].unique()
Segment_list 

array(['A', 'B'], dtype=object)
```

Now i want to traverse the list and find the amount in Value1 for each iteration so i am usinig:

```
for Segment_list in enumerate(Segment_list):
    print(df['Value1'])
```

But I getting both values instead of one by one. I just need one value for one iteration. Is this possible?

```
Expected output:

10
40
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- I recommend using [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to get the values for each group.
- For the most part, using a `for-loop` with pandas is an indication that it's probably not being done correctly or efficiently.
- Additional resources:

  - [Fast, Flexible, Easy and Intuitive: How to Speed Up Your Pandas Projects](https://realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/)
  - [Stack Overflow Pandas Tag Info Page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas/info)

### Option 1:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

np.random.seed(365)
random.seed(365)
rows = 25
data = {'n': [random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C']) for _ in range(rows)],
        'v1': np.random.randint(40, size=(rows)),
        'v2': np.random.randint(40, size=(rows))}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# groupby n
for g, d in df.groupby('n'):
#     print(g)               # use or not, as needed
    print(d.v1.values[0])    # selects the first value of each group and prints it

[out]:  # first value of each group
5
33
18
```

### Option 2:

```py
dfg = df.groupby(['n'], as_index=False).agg({'v1': list})

# display(dfg)
   n                                   v1
0  A  [5, 26, 39, 39, 10, 12, 13, 11, 28]
1  B      [33, 34, 28, 31, 27, 24, 36, 6]
2  C        [18, 27, 9, 36, 35, 30, 3, 0]
```

### Option 3:

- As stated in the comments, your data is already the result of `groupby`, and it will only ever have one value in the column for each group.

```py
dfg = df.groupby('n', as_index=False).sum()

# display(dfg)

   n   v1   v2
0  A  183  163
1  B  219  188
2  C  158  189

# print the value for each group in v1
for v in dfg.v1.to_list():
    print(v)

[out]:
183
219
158
```

### Option 4:

- Print all rows for each column

```py
dfg = df.groupby('n', as_index=False).sum()

for col in dfg.columns[1:]:  # selects all columns after n
    for v in dfg[col].to_list():
        print(v)

[out]:
183
219
158
163
188
189
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Trenton's comment that the whole point of using data frames is to avoid looping through them like this. Re-think this using a function. However the closest way to make what you've written work is something like this:

```
Segment_list = df['Name1'].unique()
for Index in Segment_list:
    print(df['Value1'][df['Name1']==Index]).iloc[0]
```

Depending on what you want to happen if there are two entries for `Name` (presumably this can happen because you use `.unique()`, This will print the sum of the Values:

```
df.groupby('Name1').sum()['Value1']
```